# Eclipse RCP cannot find applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am facing some issues integrating Eclipse RCP and Spring IOC.

Below is my approach to the process.

Steps I've done

1. Created a Bundle (Using plug-in from exisitng archives project type) which has all Spring jars.
2. Created a Simple Hello RCP application with a view.
3. Added the Bundle as a dependency to the RCP project(step2)

Created a simple class in my RCP project whose object has to instantiated through applicationContext.xml.

```
public class Triangle {
            public void draw(){
                System.out.println("Traingle drawn");
            }
       }
```

My applicationContext.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
   <bean id="JGID" class="st.Triangle"/>
</beans>
```

A code snippet part of My view where I'm fetching applicationContext.xml is as below

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("D:/applicationContext.xml");
Triangle triangle = (Triangle) applicationContext.getBean("JGID");
triangle.draw();
```

this throws error

> Cannot find class [st.Triangle] for bean with name 'JGID' defined in
>   file [D:\applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: st.Triangle

How do I resolve this error ?

As a workaround I tried the other way, also I failed as in below i.e.., using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Below is the error

> !MESSAGE Unable to create view ID st.view: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>        !STACK 0 java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened

The above code line in my Eclipse RCP applcication, where does it check or look for the xml file.

I tried the following ways.

- Placed applicationContext.xml in src folder.
- At the project folder.
- Inisde the package.

In all the 3 cases, it says `FileNotFoundException`. Where should I place the `applicationContext.xml` file to make the `applicationContext` reference to find it?

Comment: Is `st.Triangle` the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that Triangle is in "ctx" classpath?

can you instantinate another simple bean for example

`<bean id="str" class="java.lang.String" value="Hello World">`

and then call

`String str= (String) ctx.getBean("str");`

Answer (score 1):

Place the `spring-context.xml` in the class path of your application and in order to invoke it, you need the following code

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
            Triangle triangle = (Triangle) ctx.getBean("jgid");
             triangle.draw();
```

Stolen from [This site](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/quick-start-maven-spring-example/)